# Ruby Application Record: Select rows where Date's Month and Day is any of a list of Month Days

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following query selects rows where the `date_field` is a particular month and day:

```
 Table.where("DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%m/%d') = ?", "03/05")
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do something similar but instead, I supply a list of month/day strings ex: `["03/05","02,12", "12/25"]` and get all rows where `date_field` matches that particular day and month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SQL `IN` statement:

```
Table.where("DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%m/%d') IN ?", ["03/05", "02/12", "12/25"])
```